# Why "meinem" is used in "Er glaubt meinem Kind"?

Tags: dative, declension, possessive-pronoun

I saw this sentence in Duolingo. Is this supposed to be dative? If so, why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/glauben):

> [3] »jemandem glauben« (Dativ): sich auf jemanden vertrauensvoll verlassen

The verb *glauben* can take both an accusative and dative object. The something you believe is accusative, the person who you believe is dative.

> Ich glaube dir<sup>[dative]</sup> das<sup>[accusative]</sup> nicht.

The dative form of *mein* is *meinem*. Again, [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/mein) is quite a good help.

Thus, it's correct to say:

> Er glaubt meinem Kind.

Answer (score -2):

This is a possessive pronoun, dative, "male" grammar-gender.
See: http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/lernen.php?menu_id=77

Comment: OP already used "possessive pronoun" as tag, "suggested" dative himself. The only information you added is wrong, because "Kind" is neuter, not masculine. And you didn't say **why**; which is the actual question.